# Pass input text to client side and save as variable

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a script which exports a CSV from Google Sheets.  This CSV is exported to a Drive folder, and I initially placed an ID in the code using var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID goes here");

Now, I want to make the export location dynamic for my users.  I also want them to select the frequency of automated exports.  I created an html file and call a dialog box up for users to input their desired ID and frequency.

```
function openFolderForm() {
 
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('html')
        .setHeight(525)
        .setWidth(800);
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Export Settings');
}
```

In the html file, I have..

```
<form id="form">
    <div class="block form-group">
    <input type='text' name='IDdrive' id="IDdrive" style="width: 300px;"/>
    </div>
    <br>
    <p>Frequency?</p>

    <div> 
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radioDaily">
    <label for="radioDaily">Daily</label>
    </div>

    <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radioWeekly">
    <label for="radioWeekly">Weekly</label>
    </div>

    <button type = "submit" class = "action"
      onClick="google.script.run.updateSettings();">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Finally, in my code I have...

```
function updateSettings(form) {
var formQ1 = form.IDdrive;
if (form.radioDaily == true) { var formQ2 = 1; } else { var formQ2 = 7}

};

function exportCSV() {
  var changelogSheetName = "data";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var tab = ss.getSheetByName('data');
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(formQ1); //putting in dynamic form
 etc etc etc

function createTimeTrigger() {
 ScriptApp.newTrigger("exportCSV")
  .timeBased()
  .atHour(3)
  .inTimezone("America/Los_Angeles")
  .everyDays(formQ2)  //input radio variable answer here
  .create();
}

};
```

However, my code is not working.  The variables for the form answers are not passing to client side successfully.  The code does work if I put in the ID directly.

I realize that this has been asked in various forms already on this site, but I have read most of those threads and have still been unable to resolve.  Could someone help out of Scripts App newbie please? :)

Full code below, starting with .gs :

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Scripts')
      .addItem('Export CSV', 'exportCSV')
      .addItem('Update export settings', 'openFolderForm')
      .addToUi();
}

function openFolderForm() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('html').setHeight(525).setWidth(800);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Export Settings');
  }

function updateSettings(form) {
var formQ1 = form.IDdrive;
if (form.radioDaily == true) { var formQ2 = 1; } else { var formQ2 = 7};
google.script.host.close();
};

function exportCSV() {
  var changelogSheetName = "data";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var tab = ss.getSheetByName('data');
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(formQ1);
  //export code here
}


function convertRangeToCsvFile_(csvFileName, sheet) {
  
  var activeRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  try {
    var data = activeRange.getValues();
    var csvFile = undefined;

    
    if (data.length > 1) {
      var csv = "";
      for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
          if (data[row][col].toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
            data[row][col] = "\"" + data[row][col] + "\"";
          }
        }

      
        if (row < data.length-1) {
          csv += data[row].join(",") + "\r\n";
        }
        else {
          csv += data[row];
        }
      }
      csvFile = csv;
    }
    return csvFile;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
  }
}

function createTrigger() {

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('exportCSV')
      .timeBased()
      .atHour(3)
      .everyDays(formQ2) //radio question here
      .inTimezone("America/Los_Angeles")
      .create();
```

and HTML full...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <title><b>Output Folder</b></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>Enter the ID of your output folder.  A Drive ID is made up by the characters after the last /folder/ in the URL</p>
  
    <form id="form">
    <div class="block form-group">
 
    <input type='text' name='IDdrive' id="IDdrive" style="width: 300px;"/>
    </div>

  <div> 
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radioDaily"> <label for="radioDaily">Daily</label>
  </div>
  <div>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radioWeekly"> <label for="radioWeekly">Weekly</label>
  </div>

  <br>
  <div class="inline form-group">
  <input type="button" value="Submit" class="action" onClick="google.script.run.updateSettings();" /> //or "google.script.run.updateSettings(this.parentNode);"
  <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="cancel" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />
  </div>

  <br>
  </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share the errors you are getting and any other relevant info to reproduce them?

Comment: No specific errors.  Just the expected action not occurring.  Even when I try a more simple action, such as just logging something - it does not occur.  Therefore, I believe the issue is with the pass to client side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your not passing anything to updateSettings `google.script.run.updateSettings();`>

I would do it like this:

```
<input type = "button"  value="Submit" onClick="google.script.run.updateSettings(this.parentNode);" />
```

I'm running this as a dialog and it runs okay now.  I added values to the radio buttons and now the weekly one returns 'weekly' and the daily one returns 'daily' and the IDdrive returns a string.

gs:

```
function openFolderForm() {  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah1').setHeight(525).setWidth(800), 'Export Settings');
}

function updateSettings(form) {
  console.log(form)
  var formQ1=form.IDdrive;
  if (form.radioDaily == true) { var formQ2 = 1; } else { var formQ2 = 7}
}

function exportCSV() {
  var changelogSheetName = "data";
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheets=ss.getSheets();
  var tab=ss.getSheetByName('data');
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById(formQ1);  
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <title><b>Output Folder</b></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Enter the ID of your output folder. A Drive ID is made up by the characters after the last /folder/ in the URL</p>
    <form>
      <input type='text' name='IDdrive' id="IDdrive" style="width: 300px;"/><br />
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radioDaily" value="daily"> <label for="radioDaily">Daily</label><br />
      <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radioWeekly" value="weekly"> <label for="radioWeekly">Weekly</label><br />
      <input type="button" value="Submit" class="action" onClick="google.script.run.updateSettings(this.parentNode);" />
      <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="cancel" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Cooper, but I am still not passing back the variables.  When I Logger.log(form.IDdrive) it does not pass the entered text.  Do you mind having another look please?

Comment: What was the error?  Still nothing on my end unfortunately.  I can't even get it to make any action at all.  Even if I make the updateSettings function be google.script.host.close(); ....

Comment: are you able to get the var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById(formQ1) bit working?  Mine remains undefined when I run the exportCSV function...I'm wondering if it is storing the formQ1 as a different data type? 

Separately, will the criteria put into the form last between sessions if the user closes Sheets?

Comment: I didn't actually work on that part at all. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I imagine that you realize that `var formQ1=form.IDdrive;` does not make it global to exportCSV()

Comment: Yes, I do.  However, can't that be resolved by adding "form" to the function exportCSV(form)?  How would you make it global otherwise?

Comment: Well that's not making it global.  It's just making it  a parameter for the exportCSV() function.  The question I have is where is the CSV coming from?

Comment: The exportCSV is coming from a tab in the Sheet.  I can add the code to the original question...see above for the new section

Comment: What is best practice to create it globally (and to remember the input text even when closing and logging out of the Sheets file)?

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work.  The secret was needed to just JSON to properly store the form input criteria.

**CODE**

```
function updateSettings(formObject) {
    var uiForm = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      JSON.stringify(formObject);
  
     
      var formText = formObject.formQ1;
      var formRadio = formObject.formQ2;
      
      if (formRadio == "Daily") { var frequency = 1; } else { var frequency = 7};
etc etc
```

**HTML**

```
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); google.script.run.updateSettings(this); google.script.host.close();">
    <div>
    <input type='text' name='formQ1' id="formQ1" style="width: 300px;"/>
    </div>
 
  <div class="inline form-group"> 
  <input type="radio" name="formQ2" id="formQ2" value="Daily" /> <label for="radioDaily">Daily</label>
  </div>
  <div>
  <input type="radio" name="formQ2" id="formQ2" value="Weekly" /> <label for="radioWeekly">Weekly</label>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="inline form-group">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"  style="color:#4285F4"/>
  <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="cancel" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />
```

Comment: I think  using the value attribute for the radio buttons helped a lot.  When you're first building your code I'd recommend keeping your formatting to a minimum and focus on the code.  Once it's working then you can mess with the css and other formatting options.  Although I have to admit that I'm rather extreme in that regard because all of my personal apps are black on white.

Comment: Thanks Cooper.  Checkout the "exportCSV" portion of code I just updated in the original question